# Is there any push service which does not rely on GCM on android?

Tags: android, push

I checked mixpanel and airship today. Both rely on GCM to do push on Android devices. I'm wondering is there any good library and service which does not rely on GCM that I can use for push to an Android device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your particular concern with GCM? GCM should offer the best power consumption, and only an OS-supplied daemon like GCM's can be assured not to be killed due to low memory conditions, task killers, etc.

Comment: the concern with gcm is that its not reliable. Sometimes it fails to deliver messages.